# android programatically position dialog under specific view in CustomView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-custom-view, android-dialogfragment

in android kotlin app I created my own custom spinner (I used dialogFragment for spinner to achieve this). Now when I show it on click, I want it to always be positioned under the specific view in my CustomView in which I open this spinnerDialog.

My code goes like this:

```
 private fun openSpinnerDialog() {
        binding?.let {
            val location = IntArray(2)
            it.spinnerImage.getLocationOnScreen(location)

            val dialogFragment =
                SeeAllSpinnerDialog(location[0], location[1])


            (seeAllContext as? FragmentActivity)?.supportFragmentManager?.let {
                dialogFragment.show(
                    it,
                    SeeAllSpinnerDialog.SPINNER_DIALOG
                )
            }
            }
}
```

"spinnerImage" is small image and I want to locate my custom spinner dialog under this view.
My spinnerDialogFragment shortened code:

```
class SeeAllSpinnerDialog(var xPosition: Int,var yPosition: Int) : DialogFragment(), SpinnerListener {

......


  override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        setDialogPosition()
    }

private fun setDialogPosition() {
    val window = dialog?.window
    val params = window?.attributes
    params?.x =
        xPosition
    params?.y =
        yPosition
    window?.attributes = params
}

}
```

So in my Customview on click I get the position x and y of the "spinnerImage" view, I send it to my spinnerDialog and use it to set the position.
But this code does not work as expected, position is wrong.

to be more precise when I set code like thi for testing:

```
private fun setDialogPosition() {
        val window = dialog?.window
        val params = window?.attributes
        params?.x = 0
        params?.y = 0
        window?.attributes = params
    }
```

I would expect my view to be on the top left part of the custom view (android coordinate system (0,0) position is on top left. But instead it positions itself somewhere in the middle of the custom view.

I did positioning of views programatically before, what am I doing wrong in this example..?
Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the only thing that was missing is the line:

```
window?.setGravity(Gravity.TOP or Gravity.START)
```

This way, my dialog starts at the top left part of screen and than the calculation:

```
 val params = window?.attributes
    params?.x =
        xPosition
    params?.y =
        yPosition
    window?.attributes = params
```

works like charm. I knew it is probably 1 or 2 line mistake since it worked before but it is usually like that in programming. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a dialog. Your use case could be completely covered by a [PopupWindow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow) - it is not a dialog but rather an arbitrary view that can be shown and anchored to a specific location or widget on the screen.

It is really easy to achieve use code like this to calculate needed view position on the screen:

```
val View?.viewRect: Rect?
    get() =
        this?.run {
            try {
                val location = IntArray(2)
                getLocationOnScreen(location)
                Rect().apply {
                    left = location[0]
                    top = location[1]
                    right = left + width
                    bottom = top + height
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                null
            }
        }
```

And then just show a popup where it is needed:

```
private fun openSpinnerDialog() {
        binding?.let {
            val location = IntArray(2)
            it.spinnerImage.viewRect?.apply{
                // Instead of ... there should be a proper view inflation and other correct params of your desired popup
                PopupWindow(...).showAtLocation(parent, Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, left, bottom) // you can also use showAsDropDown for the dropdown like behaviour
            }
        }
}
popup.showAtLocation(parent, Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, location.left, location.bottom)
```

The code may need some adjustments as I've written it on the spot and never tested it.

By the way, location calculation could also apply to the dialog you want to show - I am not sure though.

Hope it helps.

Comment: my dialog class contains all the logic for custom spinner. It has adapter that fills data and everything. If I understood you well, you think I could instead of dialogFragment inherit PopupWindow class in my CustomSpinner class and write all my logic there. That sounds fine, but what is the difference between positioning dialog and Popup window. Shouldn't calculating position be identical for these 2. Why would it be different for popupWindow, you are using same logic as I did for calculating x and y position if I see well.

Comment: @Kratos I've written in the answer that the position calculation may also apply to the dialog - but I don't know never tried it - it is just your calculation was incomplete, and I have added the proper version. Secondly, you should not extend from the PopupWindow - you need to inflate your view and pass it to the PopupWindow upon creation - look into the documentation and google it - everything is there. Regarding the logic of the dialog inside the dialog - it is another question, but you can create a separate holder for just a logic that can work with any UI - either dialog or simple view

Comment: @Kratos Move the extension outside the class - it should be a global function(not inside any other object). It is basic Kotlin. In order to even start the Android development I would suggest you to learn the language and tools provided by the language and plugin. The code works.

Comment: Well that was harsh, but no problem doesn't bother me a lot. Anyways I found the solution. My calculation is fine and I missed only 1 line of code: window?.setGravity(Gravity.TOP or Gravity.START).
I upvoted your answer but we have to be fair, 1 line of code change is easier and more straight forward solution in this situation. So it would be unfair to accept dfferent solution. Thanks for your answer!